# How to understand the channel communication rules in golang memory model?

Tags: go, channel, memory-model, happens-before

Learning golang on the way, I got a little confused when trying to understand the channel communications described in the memory model spec as below:

> 1. A send on a channel happens before the corresponding receive from that channel completes.
> 2. The closing of a channel happens before a receive that returns a zero value because the channel is closed.
> 3. **A receive from an unbuffered channel happens before the send on that channel completes.**
> 4. The kth receive on a channel with capacity C happens before the k+Cth send from that channel completes.

The first 2 rules are clear and easy to understand, while I really got confused about the 3rd rule, which seems opposite to others... Did I miss anything special about **unbuffered channel**? Or am I correct If I take it like the below with the example in the spec:

```
var c = make(chan int)
var a string

func f() {
    a = "hello, world"
    <-c    // A
}
func main() {
    go f()
    c <- 0 // B
    print(a)
}
```

For an unbuffered channel, the send operation(B) is blocked until the receiver gets ready to receive the value(A)? (like: B starts and does not return until A executes) Is it accurate?

And I find the following statements in [Effective Go spec](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels), but there's still discrepancy from my understanding... So can someone please explain this in a simple and straightforward way?

> Receivers always block until there is data to receive. **If the channel
>   is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the
>   value.** If the channel has a buffer, the sender blocks only until the
>   value has been copied to the buffer; if the buffer is full, this means
>   waiting until some receiver has retrieved a value.

Comment: "Happens Before" HB has a very special meaning and is only loosely related to a traditional "before" in linear time. You can have two events `x` and `y` with both relations holding: `x HB y` and `y HB x`. Rule 1 and 3 together roughly say: "Send and receive on an unbuffered channel properly synchronise and work like you would expect it (no matter how fancy the CPU reorganises your instructions, how aggressively your memory caches cache and what not."

Comment: @Volker hmm...still confused on why `x HB y` and `y HB x` both hold true, haha. Possibly, I need to split an event `e` to different atomic phases, such as beginning, processing and ending, in order to understand this `happens-before` term properly...Thanks!

Comment: HB does not mean that something actually happens to an earlier time than something else, it is just a convenient mnemonic. The HB graph establishes by the partial HB order determines which memory operations are visible where. It is a _model_ and not reality. What HB establishes are guarantees of synchronisation. It says _nothing_ about what actually happens.

Comment: clearly the term `happens-before` is misleading, see this example https://play.golang.org/p/1NJrpo-hnjQ... i have found myself i little confused about how the executions code flows according using channels as signals.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The sentence you've highlighted is the simple explanation you are looking for.

> If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value.

It's another way of saying  point 3:

> A receive from an unbuffered channel happens before the send on that channel completes.

When you send on an unbuffered channel, the **sender blocks** until the receiver has taken the value. This means the **receive happens before the send completes**.

A buffered channel is different, because the value has somewhere to go. If you're still confused, an example might help:

Say I want to leave a package at your house:

- If the channel is buffered, you have somewhere for me to leave the package - perhaps a mailbox. This means I can complete my task of giving you the package (sending on the channel) before you receive it (when you check your mailbox).
- If the channel is not buffered, I have to wait by your front door until you come and take the package off me. You receive the package before I am done with my task of delivering it to you.

---

> For an unbuffered channel, the send operation(B) is blocked until the receiver gets ready to receive the value(A)? (like: B starts and does not return until A executes) Is it accurate?

Yes. This is correct.

Comment: Excellent example, that's so helpful! Thanks!

Comment: so  "happens before" is totally different from meaning "executed before", very good explain btw.. although i don't understand what is the important thing to renember about this.. i mean, what is the important thing i should take care about if sender happens before or reciever happens before, as long there is no deadlock.. i would like to see code examples, explaining these two scenarios (Timothy your post is excelent, but is still thing how it can affect our code design decisions). Thanks to all

Comment: Excellent example, easy to understand! Thanks

Comment: Nicely explained, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> For an unbuffered channel, the send operation(B) is blocked until the receiver gets ready to receive the value(A)? (like: B starts and does not return until A executes) Is it accurate?

Yes, this is accurate. Like the documentation says if a channel is unbuffered then sender will block  until the value has been received. If the value is never received you will get a deadlock and the program will time out, like in [this](https://play.golang.org/p/DEqGRQNQRc) example:

```
var c = make(chan int)

func main() {
    c <- 0
    println("Will not print")
}
```

So an unbuffered channel will block at the send operation until the receiver is ready to receive the value, even if that takes a while. With a buffered channel however the blocking will take place at the receive operation. [This](https://play.golang.org/p/g3UkSvNqYW) example shows how the unbuffered channel waits for the value to be received, but the buffered does not:

```
package main

import "time"

var c chan int
var a string

func f() {
    time.Sleep(3)
    a = "hello, world"
    <-c // A
}
func test() {
    a = "goodbye"
    go f()
    c <- 0 // B
    println(a)
}

func main() {
    // Unbuffered
    c = make(chan int)
    test()

    // Buffered
    c = make(chan int, 1)
    test()
}
```

Outputs:

```
hello, world
goodbye
```

Comment: I think you have `A` and `B` around the wrong way. The OP's statement is correct - `B` does block until `A` happens (forever if `A` never happens).

Comment: @TimothyJones Yes you are correct. The example I provided reflects that, but my statement does not.

Comment: @JackGore Good examples for buffered vs. unbuffered channels, it's clear now. And also interesting timeout example. Thanks!

Comment: @JackGore I think it's better to call it a `deadlock` example instead of timeout: the program exits because of a deadlock. Also I find [this blog about timeout](https://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and), interestingly it mentioned a non-blocking send on an unbuffered channel via select.

Answer (score 0):

For me it started making sense why that has to be that way after i read the next rule:

> The kth receive on a channel with capacity C happens before the k+Cth send from that channel completes.

It is kind of the same, you need to be able sync the routines, so the receiver waits for the sender.